# why it doesn't add image to flow pane?

Tags: java, javafx, flowpane

i have the blow code the it doesn't work i can't understand what's matter?

```
FlowPane flowPane = new FlowPane();
System.out.println("log:brows song");
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Image image = new Image(new File("sample/image/2.jpg").toURI().toString());
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
    flowPane.getChildren().add(imageView);
}
mainAnchorePaneArtist.getChildren().clear();

mainAnchorePaneArtist.getChildren().add(flowPane);
```

it clear all the node in mainAnchorePaneArtist but it doesn't add the flow pane or may be don't show it !!

Comment: Does it throw any exception ?

Comment: `File file = new File("sample/image/2.jpg");
    System.out.println(file.exists());` will probably output false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried with your code and it works: please verify the image location, maybe image location has problem.
Try this:

```
public class MainClass extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
              AnchorPane group = new AnchorPane();   
              Scene scene = new Scene(group ,600, 300);  
              primaryStage.setTitle("Sample Application"); 
              primaryStage.setScene(scene); 
              FlowPane flowPane = new FlowPane();
              System.out.println("log:brows song");
              for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                  Image image = new Image(new File("2.jpg").toURI().toString());
                  ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
                  flowPane.getChildren().add(imageView);
              }
              group.getChildren().clear();

              group.getChildren().add(flowPane);
              primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      launch(args);
  }

}
```